# Embed the output of a <form> in HTML

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a php script I can't edit because it's external to my website.
After the `<form>` submit, it redirects me to an external image, generated by the php script. That image will vary deppending on the form's values.
And I want the image, instead, to be shown inside of my website.
This is the code:

```
<FORM target=_blank action="https://www.cuentadigital.com/generador.php" METHOD="get">
<input type="text" name="codigo">
<input type="hidden" value="1234" name="id">
<input type="hidden" value="69" name="precio">
<input type="submit" value="Comprar">
</form>
```

What can I do? I hope you can help me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use iframe inside your main html, Iframe allows you to perform get/post the form inside hrml and the original html form remains static.

You can use ajax request to get this image (ajax get request), you will get the image from the server in response. 
If you want the image to show in your website, you can set frame src attribute once you get the dynamic link in response.

Comment: iframe would be an awesome idea but I don't know how to redirect it to the generated link if this link and the generated image it will be different deppending on what the user wrote in the field "codigo".

Comment: I will suggest use iframe and make a get request to the link written in action in your form. You can set frame src attribute once you get generated link in ajax response from server.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think now I understand what you mean, I will try it and tell you if it works!

Comment: ok try it and if in case it does not work, try to use jquery ajax request, that will definitely work.

Comment: It did work, and the source Sean provided was also helpful, a lot! :)
Thanks guys, if I can now get  the html file to change after the form's submit the website will be finished!

Answer (score 0):

create a file called `image.php` that looks like this:

```
<?php
// build request
$formfields = array(
    'codigo' => 'ABCDEFG',
    'id' => '1234',
    'precio' => '69'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.cuentadigital.com/generador.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($formfields));

// execute request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$image_data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

// output
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
echo $image_data;
?>
```

and then in your HTML:

```
<img src="image.php" />
```

Comment: Would this work if I needed each user to write a his own custom value in "codigo"? That value is meant to let me differ between each user.

Comment: in that case,  iframe is your friend. Include an iframe in your page like so: `<iframe id="x" name="x" width="250" height="250"></iframe>` and then target that iframe with your form: `<form target="x"...`